# White image gradient from right

Tags: html, css, image, transparency

I want the exact gradient that is used on the big image near the top of this web page: http://www.cohabs.com/

I can get something quite close using this:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(237,237,237,0) 0%, rgba(246,246,246,0.53) 53%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%), url(../images/firstImage.jpg) no-repeat;
```

But its not quite the same, as my method seems to dim even colour on the far left.

I did try view the source of that website I linked but I couldn't find anything that helped..

I used this website to create my gradient.

http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/JRzprR)

Along with the above `-webkit-linear-gradient` you need other properties to make it work.

```
.container { position: relative; }
.container:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right,hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 40%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(270deg,hsla(0,0%,100%,.8),hsla(0,0%,100%,0) 40%);
    content: '';
}
```

Markup for the above should be

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.cohabs.com/files/library/assets/homapage/slider/Homepage_web.jpg?thumb=hero"> 
</div>
```

Comment: Struggling with it a bit, when i make my image 100% it obviously taked up the whole screen, and when i remove that, the gradient is still on the far right of the screen, and doesn't have the correct height either.

Comment: Ok which means your HTML structuring is not inline with the styles, can you update the Codepen above to what your HTML looks like and what you have been trying

Comment: Ok, you just need to remove the `width: 100%` from the `.firstImage` class, Simple! **You have removed 100% from the image but not from its container(remember you have applied the gradient to its container not the image itself)** :-)